# Upload Video (mp4) to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am following [Transfer data with the Data Movement library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) to upload a video (mp4) from my local machine to Azure Blob Storage.

Here the code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureUpload
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<<ConnectionString>>");
                ExecuteChoice(account);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void ExecuteChoice(CloudStorageAccount account)
        {
            TransferLocalFileToAzureBlob(account).Wait();
        }

        public static string GetSourcePath()
        {
            return "E:\\SampleVideo.mp4";
        }

        public static CloudBlockBlob GetBlob(CloudStorageAccount account)
        {
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("<<Container>>");
            container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MoD0604");
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "video/mp4"; // -- added this line to set ContentType as my video file is mp4
            return blob;
        }

        public static async Task TransferLocalFileToAzureBlob(CloudStorageAccount account)
        {
            string localFilePath = GetSourcePath();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlob(account);
            Console.WriteLine("\nTransfer started...");
            await TransferManager.UploadAsync(localFilePath, blob);
            Console.WriteLine("\nTransfer operation complete.");
        }
    }
}
```

The sample provided in the link do not have the following line in **GetBlob** method

```
blob.Properties.ContentType = "video/mp4"; // -- added this line to set ContentType as my video file is mp4.
```

I tried with ContentType and without ContentType. In both the cases, it looks like file is uploaded to the Blob. The only difference seems to be with ContentType as shown in below picture.

[image]

The issue is while trying to download any of the files, it resulted in a warning error and later neither of the file played and the following error is shown.

[image]

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the header is set correctly, Windows doesn't know what to do with a file without an extension, that's why you can't open it. If you append the proper extension when downloading the blob, it will work since you (most likely) have an application that is associated with that specific file type.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with extension. While creating `CloudBlockBlob` I should pass the extension as well. i.e `CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MoD0604");` should be `CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MoD0604.mp4");` **.mp4** is added to the name.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [the new SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) from Microsoft for working with Azure Blob Storage.
Install **Azure.Storage.Blobs** NuGet package.

```
        string connString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yourAccountName;AccountKey=yourAccountKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
        {
            ContentType = "video/mp4"
        };

        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(connString, "container1", "SampleVideo.mp4");
        blobClient.Upload("E:\\SampleVideo.mp4", blobHttpHeaders);
```