# Best way to upload medium sized videos to azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, video, file-upload, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am currently on a student plan for azure (gotta stay finessing as a college student lol) and am looking for the best way to upload videos to azure blob storage. Currently, I am using an azure function api to upload the video, but I am encountering a "Javascript heap out of memory" error when I try and multiparts parse big video files.

Ideally, I'd be able to quickly upload 3.5 minute music videos from mobile and desktop to azure blob storage with this method.

Either a better way of uploading videos to blob storage from my front-end or a solution for the javascript heap out of memory error would be amazing help.

Here's the link to that other post, if you are curious: [How to fix JavaScript heap out of memory on multipart.Parse() for azure function api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74621076/17517579)

Answer (score 0):

***Approaches:***

1. After a workaround based on your issue, I would suggest that you use [Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/).
2. Media Services can be integrated with Azure CDN. Refer to check [Media Services-Managing streaming endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-manage-streaming-endpoints).

> All supported formats use HTTP to transport data and benefit from HTTP caching. In live streaming, actual video/audio data is separated into fragments, which are cached in CDNs.

3. To start, I recommend that you use the Azure Storage SDK with Node.JS. The SDK will handle everything for you.  Attaching few uploaders below to check accordingly.
   [Upload a video to Azure Blob examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/examples)
4. Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) & [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374786/upload-video-mp4-to-azure-blob-storage) by @Gopi for uploading a video with the .mp4 extension to Azure blob storage using C#.
5. You can upload a video using Azure functions directly. But to use Azure Functions, you must create a back-end component written in.NET, Java, JavaScript, or Python.
6. You can use the *"Azure Storage Rest API"* to upload files/video files using a storage account, like you mentioned. You will be able to get the desired result by using this [Azure Storage Rest -API-MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/).

Comment: Retirement notice: Azure Media Services is being retired on 30 June 2024